# How would you manage this layout with a CMS

Tags: css, content-management-system

These sort of layouts - horizontal aligned text and images lists, tend to be pretty popular on features pages of websites, ive designed one and coded it up, but its come across my mind that when the project is handed over a non technical person can easily edit the text, but then that will set the text / image alignment off.

To fix this they would also need to edit the css, but thats not suitable for most people.

Is there a better way to manage this ?

This is the html/css im using ive also made a [jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/pudle/Qkkb4/) if any one wants a play

```
<div class="feature">
    <p class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi tempora eaque magni obcaecati quis at corrupti perferendis eum magnam ipsum maiores quod fugit dolorum odio temporibus voluptate asperiores atque esse.</p>

    <img src="http://pictures-of-cats.org/wp-content/uploads/images/bengal-cat-RAVI-w.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
</div>

<div class="feature">
    <p class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi tempora eaque magni obcaecati quis at corrupti perferendis eum magnam.</p>

    <img src="http://pictures-of-cats.org/wp-content/uploads/images/bengal-cat-RAVI-w.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {width:500px;}

p {width:280px;}
p.left {float:left; padding:30px 0 0 0;}
p.right {float:right; padding:45px 0 0 0;}

img {float:left;}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see why the alignment would mess up, if you did the HTML+CSS how I imagine it. Can you provide existing HTML example, so that perhaps we can point out how to change the underlying structure, so that alignment stays intact without the user needing to modify the CSS?

Comment: What else do you have ? What did you try ? Your question look more like : I don't know much about html layout but i want to get payed' **than** 'I have this context and this situation where i need help'

Comment: @anonymouscoward - The problem occurs if the user changes the text, so now instead of 5 lines of text, you have 3 lines so now the padding / margin on the top of the <p> tags would not be aligning the image / text correctly - as they should be horizontally aligned

Answer (score 1):

just manage your parent media markup with a css selector the 'non-technical' user will understand. Something like

```
<markup class=image-left'><markup><img/></markup></markup>
```

then show the client to use '.image-left'  and/or '.image-right'

Or better, manage your whole layout from the start, making sure your 'image' will float left or right, depending on the row you are laying.

CSS

```
.markup:nth-child(even) {style it to float image left}
.markup:nth-child(even) img {float:left;margin:0 10px 10px 0}
.markup:nth-child(odd) {style it to float image right}
.markup:nth-child(odd) img {float:right;margin:0 0 10px 10px}
```